# Get a unique hash value out of a combination of columns

Tags: r, hash

I have a `data.table` with 4+ columns. The first 3 are necessary to get the data about one unique individual.

```
c1   c2   c3   c4
a    c    e    other_data
a    c    e    other_data
a    c    f    other_data
a    c    f    other_data
a    d    f    other_data
b    d    g    other_data

# (c1 = "a" AND c2 = "c" AND c3 = "e") => one individual
# (c1 = "a" AND c2 = "c" AND c3 = "f") => another individual
```

I'd like to compute another column which would mark each individual :

```
c1   c2   c3   c4           unique_individual_id
a    c    e    other_data   1
a    c    e    other_data   1
a    c    f    other_data   2
a    c    f    other_data   2 
a    d    f    other_data   3 
b    d    g    other_data   4
```

I would like to get a unique hash out of the content of the 3 columns.

How would I do that in code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
as.numeric(as.factor(with(df, paste(c1, c2, c3))))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

Comment: All three answers work, but this one is the fastest according to `microbenchmark`

Comment: Similar, `c(unclass(as.factor(Reduce(paste, dat[-4]))))`. The final `c` strips off the unused levels attribute.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `interaction` to create the unique index

```
df1$unique_individual_id <- as.integer(do.call(interaction, c(df1[-4], drop = TRUE)))
df1$unique_individual_id
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can paste the values of interest (for each row, you paste together the values in columns 1, 2, and 3), convert to factor and then to integer (this will return an unique ID num for your combination.

```
df <- data.frame(c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d"), 
                 c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e"),
                 c("c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e"))
df$ID <- as.numeric(as.factor(sapply(1:nrow(df), (function(i) {paste(df[i, 1:3], collapse = "")}))))
```